# What is the id for SCP 106 head

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make SCP SL in mc but I need SCP 106's head, I checked name mc's database but I could not find it. this is all in Minecraft Java 1.12.2.

NOTE: SCP-106 looks like a decaying old man.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

gah this question has gone on for a bit, penguin answer doesn't work so i found myself a suitable replacement for now on namemc.

Answer (score 0):

## 1.12-

### Command

```
/give @p minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"SCP106"}
```

### Put On Head

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"SCP106"}
```

Comment: person wearing plague doctor mask not 106

Comment: i have Fixed it

Comment: no i meant its ment to be 106 NOT plauge doctor

Comment: i do not need a plauge doctor mask, i need scp-106 Penguin

Comment: @anomanous you have changed your request twice now, what do you really want?

Comment: i never changed it, you took it to mean something differently then what it was

Comment: and the player SCP106 does not have the skin i require